# VeNiShmartem - Positive or Negative?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, mitzvah, health-safety-shmira

VeNiShmartem  Meod LeNafshotheichem ([Devarim 4:15](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9968/showrashi/true#v15)), the Mitzvah of self-preservation - requiring that we guard our health - sounds rather proactive. However, it is written with the word ShMR, to "guard", which is seen in the Mitzvah to guard Shabbath as the word which gives force to the negative commandment - the prohibition - not to violate the laws of the Sabbath, as distinct from the positive commanment to "remember" the Sabbath.

Does this mean that VeNiShmartem is a negative Mitzvah, a prohibition? If so, does every unsafe action or unhealthy indulgence constitute a violation? *And if so*, would it follow that it should be punishable by Beith Din with proper warning and witnesses, etc.?

Comment: I don't see it in Rambam's 613. Are you sure it's deoraita?

Comment: @doubleaa No way, bru.

Comment: @doubleaa Can't look it up now but try Deut 4:15

Comment: bru = jew + bro ?

Comment: @doubleaa Nah, I was adopted by Safricans in Yeshivah.

Comment: @SethJ http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=62

Answer (score 3):

The context of the verse ([Deuteronomy 4:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0504.htm)) clearly has nothing to do with preserving one's health. I think it is understood that this is not an actual lav or aseh but some kind of [drasha/asmachta](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=32b&format=pdf). The verse itself clearly refers to refraining from forms of idol worship.

Just to add some support to this: @DoubleAA [noted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17750/1601) that the Rambam does not list this as a mitzva. Furthermore, when [the Rambam](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93) in his Mishneh Torah talks about the importance of being healthy he conspicuously does not mention this verse; something he would never do in the Mishneh Torah otherwise.

Comment: While I think you are right, a source (perhaps where the asmachta is) would be invaluable.

Comment: @DoubleAA best I could do for now.

Answer (score 0):

[Menachos 99b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=99b&format=pdf) says that wherever it says "hishamer," "pen," or "al," it is a negative commandment.

It appears to me that it is not the root Sh-M-R that is a negative commandment, but rather the word "hishamer." If so, "venishmartem" is not a negative commandment. However, even if every instance of Sh-M-R *is* a negative commandment, it is not punishable by beis din, because it is a lav she'ein bo maaseh (negative commandment which involves no action), and we don't lash for a lav she'ein bo maaseh. (Although it can be done with an action — e.g. stabbing yourself — since it *can* be done without an action, we don't lash for it, Sefer HaChinuch 94.)

Comment: But compare to Chinuch 11

Comment: Note that there's an intermediate possibility: that any time _sh-m-r_ appears in _binyan nif'al_ it's a negative command. Then _v'nishmartem_ would be a negative command.

Comment: Peculiar! See Shu"A Ch"M 427:8