# Are there any responsa that encourage or require maintaining health insurance?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, money, health-safety-shmira, modern-times

Are there any responsa in the literature that either encourage or require people to maintain health insurance, perhaps as a fulfillment of the [obligation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17750/venishmartem-positive-or-negative) to guard one's health, or in line with any other commandments or Torah principles? Of course, this would mainly be relevant in a society in which expensive and effective healthcare is available for purchase (i.e. modern times) and not automatically, universally paid for by the government (e.g. in the United States, and to varying degrees, many other countries).

(Hat tip for the question to [William Friedman](https://www.facebook.com/wfriedman/posts/10152895488258510).)

<sup>Related questions:

[Is a person obligated to purchase life insurance?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33572/is-a-person-obligated-to-purchase-life-insurance)

[Does the existence of insurance affect end-of-life Halacha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3057/does-the-existence-of-insurance-affect-end-of-life-halacha)</sup>

Comment: Seems like a "borderline question". There is a Torah obligation to take care of your health as best as possible. IMO, if you can't afford to pay for your own health care on your own, but having insurance helps make the healthcare affordable, then, it seems that you would be obligated. Question is, what if you are too poor to pay for insurance? In that case, I think doctors and hospitals are obligated to care for you gratis. But if you can afford to pay out of pocket, I don't see any obligation to buy insurance.

Comment: *If* there is an obligation to purchase health insurance, it would seem more likely to come from the idea of לוה רשע ולא ישלם, much more than from health care access. Unless you are very poor and being given the health insurance, health insurance is all about financial protection.

Comment: @Yishai, that's true in an environment in which all effective healthcare measures are available for everyone who needs them, regardless of ability to pay. This is not the case in the United States; I'm not sure about other countries. It is definitely possible, in the US, to need or be able to benefit from a therapeutic measure and to have *no access* to that measure if you don't have the ability to pay for it.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, it is also definitely possible to be able to benefit from a therapeutic measure and to have no access to it because insurance won't cover it. In fact, by that argument, it might be *ossur* to accept medicare, since if medicare refuses the procedure, no medicare-accepting doctor can do the procedure for money.

Comment: @Yishai, there's no point in arguing about the details of the *metziut*. My only point is that it's plausible, at least in the US, to expect that purchasing insurance increases one's access to theraputic measures, which could put such purchase into the the category of preserving health and not just a monetary matter. (But anyway, in the case in your argument, maintaining insurance doesn't decrease one's access, since one has the roughly same ability to pay out-of-pocket that one would have had without the insurance.)

Comment: Moving on (not agreeing, but no point in arguing), well, of some relevance (I only have oral history) was the Lubavitcher Rebbe telling his followers to *refuse* health insurance from Israel when they conditioned it on party membership (this was in the 1950's), because the Previous Rebbe had forbidden membership in any Israeli (secular?) party.

Comment: Not a responsum and not well sourced, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but: "One is free to buy insurance… to fulfill the obligation not to burden others. And… one is responsible for caring for others, even if they were negligent. However, this is never a pure entitlement: those who were negligent [must] reimburse their providers. Granted that the prime responsibility is the individual’s…, the Torah does allow… the community to… mandate participation" (http://chabad.org/1914545). But that doesn't address the issues you raise, Isaac Moses, in your comments, above, to @Yishai.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66128

Comment: is healthcare a human right or a privilege?